# Clarification on treating a variable as constant in partial derivatives vs. allowing it to vary in total differentials

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I am taking a course in mathematics for physicists and in one lesson we discussed total differentials ($df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$). There is a point that's puzzling me (I know that it is basic, sorry): the apparent contradiction in the treatment of a variable as both constant and varying in different contexts. Specifically, I'm trying to reconcile how, in the calculation of partial derivatives, we treat a variable (let's say y) as constant, yet in the context of total differentials, we allow the same variable (y) to vary (as indicated by its non-zero differential dy). This seems contradictory to me, as we're simultaneously treating y as both a constant and a variable.

How can we justify treating a variable as constant in one scenario while allowing it to vary in another scenario?

Could someone provide an explanation that clarifies this situation, other than the "different perspectives" or "two contexts" explanation?

Thank you for any insights or references you can provide!

Comment: $df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,dy$ has two closely related meanings: 1) exterior derivative of the $0$-form $f\,.$ 2) Short version of $$\frac{df}{dt}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\,\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\,\frac{dy}{dt}$$ where $x,y$ are now functions of $t\,.$ This is also known as the chain rule. In either of the two meanings the questions you are asking do not even arise. BTW this is total standard and you should not ask here for a detailed step-by-step explanation that goes beyond ... .

Comment: Let $\Delta f$ be the amount by which $f$ changes when its input changes from $(x,y)$ to $(x+\Delta x, y+ \Delta y)$. Then $\Delta f \approx \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} \Delta x + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} \Delta y$. The approximation is good when $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$ are small. You can observe this yourself by doing experiments with a function such as $f(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$. Try approximating $f(3.01, 4.02)$. It will be illuminating.

Comment: I'm not sure of a good way to write this as an answer, but your question seems not far from "in the calculation of $x^2+x^3$, we are squaring $x$ in one term but not squaring it in the other. This seems contradictory to me." I think getting into the weeds of the details of the extent to which a partial derivative is or is not holding a variable constant may be a red herring. Just like the squaring in one term doesn't force something about the other term, the same is true of any sum across all of mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say we have a function of two variables (x and y), $f:{\mathbb{R}}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

What's the meaning of the partial derivative with respect to x?
The partial derivative with respect to x tells us what is the slope of the function $f$ only in the x direction. how is it doing so?

if we change only the x values that the function f receives and do not change the y values, starting from the point $P=(x_0,y_0)$, we "slice" the function f in the x direction at the point P (i.e. we get the graph of the function f when intersected by the plane $y=y_0$). this gives us a function of one variable - $f(x,y_0)$, which we know how to take its derivative (this is the single variable case). I think the notation and a subtle point are the reasons for your confusion, so I will write things using slightly different notation and it will hopefully make things clearer:

$(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})\rvert_{(x_0,y_0)}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac {f(x_0+h,y_0)-f(x_0,y_0)}{h}$

First, you can see it is not really that the second variable is constant, rather we do not change the input value for y (i.e. the second variable) *in* the function; there is no relation between that that we do not change the second input of the function f and that the variable itself is "constant". we do not assume anything on y, we just say that we do not change the y value we give to f, but not that y itself is constant.
secondly, now that we do not write $f(x,y)$ but instead $f(x_0,y_0)$, you can see the meaning I talked about above: we move in the x direction away from the point $P$ in small increments to find whats the slope of the function in that direction, and its not that we hold y constant in every sense, but rather that we do not change the value we give the function f (see next paragraphs).

Also, notice that $(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x})\rvert_{(x_0,y_0)}=(\frac{df(x,y_0)}{dx})\rvert_{x_0}$; this is a nice way of summarizing neatly this paragraph.

In my opinion, your question is similar to saying "If we substitute $x_0$ to $g(x)$ (some function), then x is now constant". saying this and your question is similar since in your question you basically said that the fact that we do not change $y_0$ as the value for the second input means that y is constant, and here we say that because we substituted $x_0$ as $x$ now x is a constant - and we know this is not the case, since there is no reason why substituting $x_0$ as the input to the function g will make the variable itself a constant.

Answer (score 2):

Left $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to  \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. For fixed $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ we define the partial derivatives of $f$ at $(x,y)$ by
$$
\tag{1}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(x+ h, y) - f(x,y)}{h}\in \mathbb{R}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x,y) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ f(x, y+h) - f(x,y)}{h}\in \mathbb{R}.
$$
So for example in the definition of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x,y)$ the second variable is fixed and the first variable varies, because we add $h$ to it which is varied to compute the limit.
It is not really $x$ that varies but the first variable since both $x$ and $y$ are fixed through the whole process.

By computing the above limits for all points $(x,y) \in  \mathbb{R}^2$ we obtain two linear functions $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  : \mathbb{R}^2 \to  \mathbb{R}$, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}  : \mathbb{R}^2 \to  \mathbb{R}$ defined by the above formulas.

Now we can for example evaluate the function $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ at different  points (vary $(x,y)$).

Fix a point $p=(p_1,p_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ and let $v=(v_1,v_2)  \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a tangent vector (the change). For a tangent vector we define $dx_p(v) = v_1$ (the change in the $x$-direction when moving from $p$ to $p+v$) and $dy_p (v) = v_2$ (the change in the $y$-direction).

Define the differential $df_p : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ of $f$ at $p$ by
$$df_p (v) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (p) dx_p(v) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (p) dy_p(v). $$
Note that here the basepoint $p$ is fixed and $v$ (the change) is the variable of $df_p $.

The differential gives us the first order/linear (in $v$) change of $f$ when moving from $p$ to $p+v$:
$$
\tag{2}
f(p+v) - f(p) \approx df_p(v) .
$$

This makes total sense since for example to first order by the definition of the partial derivative (eq. (1)):
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (p) dx_p(v) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (p) v_1 \approx f(p_1 +v_1,p_2) - f(p_1,p_2)
$$
is the linear change of $f$ when moving from $p$ to $p+ (v_1,0)$, that is to say to move only in the $x$ direction.

So in total eq. (2) tells us that the first order change in $f$ when moving from $p$ to $p+v$ is the sum of the first order change of $f$ when moving from $p$ to $p+(v_1,0)$ (only moving in the $x$-direction) and the first order change of $f$ when moving from $p$ to $p+(0,v_2)$ (only moving in the $y$-direction).

Comment: Thank you,
If I get you right, we never say that either of the variables is constant?
If we do say that they are constant, then the differentials dx and dy would be both zero and then the entire expression would be zero, which does not make sense...

Comment: @E271828 I dont really understand your question unfortunatly. $dx_p$ and $dy_p$ are (obviously non zero) functions acting on tangent vectors. Could you be more specific?

Comment: our professor told us that if we hold y or x constant, then their differentials are zero. for example, in the computation of the partial derivative of f with respect to x, we hold y as a constant. so dy must be zero, and then $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$ will be zero (because dy=0), and the with same logic for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$ when calculating $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ it follows that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx$ is zero as well.

Comment: @E271828 Yes if (in my notation) the change is $v= (v_1,0)$ (only movement in $x$ direction so the second variable $y$ is constant when going from $p$ to $p+v$), then by definition $dy_p (v) =0$ and therefore $df_p (v)= \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p) dx_p(v)$ in this case. Which then leads to the partial derivative (although that would be circular since i defined partial derivatives first).

Comment: I wasn't clear enough, sorry; my question is why even though we say that x and y are constant, the total differential is not zero if we agree upon my last comment (because if x and y are constant, then dx and dy should both be zero and then the entire expression is zero).

Comment: @E271828 If the variables $x$ and $y$ are constant when going from $p$ to $p+v$, that is to say $v= (0,0)$ then of course $df_p(v) =0$, since $dx_p(v) =0$ and $dy_p(v)=0$.

Comment: I didn't mean that they are (inherently) constant - they are variables that are "made" or "treated" as constants in the definition/computation of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$, and because they are treated this way, dx and dy should be zero. your last comment is exactly what I don't get - even though x and y are variables, they are treated as constants in the computation of the partial derivative, so dx and dy are zero and hence the entire expression, but it shouldn't be this way because x and y are not really constants and f is not a constant function...

Comment: @E271828 What do $dx$ and $dy$ have to do with the partial derivative? $dx_p$ and $dy_p$ are functions acting on tangent vectors $v$ while $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$ are totally different functions of the basepoint $p$. The two are (a priori) totally unrelated functions! To me the question seems nonsensical. I defined the partial derivatives in some way and obtained a function and i defined $dx_p / dy_p$ as functions (a priori) totally unrelated to the partial derivates. So why should they be related in some way?

Comment: Thank you for helping clarify things. I think I get you now - in the partial derivative computation, we think of x or y (depending on which partial derivative we take) as constants; we do not change y in $f(x,y)$ when calculating the partial with respect to x, But it doesn't mean that they are inherently constants (since there is no assumption or requirement that x and y are constants) so dx and dy are not zero (and this is what you mean when you said that the functions you mentioned are totally unrelated?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148226/discussion-between-e271828-and-jd27).