# Tensor Calculus - Differentiation of a transformation.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, tensors

I began reading about tensor calculus recently, and I've been having trouble understanding the differentiation of a transformation.

Let's say we are in an N-dimensional space with coordinates $x^1, x^2, ..., x^N$ (Note that they are not powers here, just indices). The book I'm reading *(**Tensor Calculus** by J. L. Synge and A. Schild)* generalises a transformation of these coordinates as:

$$
(x^r)' = f^r(x^1, x^2, ..., x^N)
$$

With $r = (1, 2, ..., N)$, and **f** being an arbitrary, differentiable function $\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. At some point, however, the book says: *"differentiation of [equation above] gives us:"*

$$
d(x^r)' = \sum^{N}_{s = 1}\frac{\partial{(x^r)'}}{\partial{x^s}}dx^s
$$

And as much as I tried, I can't quite understand what this equation is supposed to mean. It seems to me like it's saying that the ordinary derivative of a scalar-valued function is the sum of its partial derivates, but it doesn't make much sense because:

1. It seems that the coordinate we're deriving $(x^r)'$ with respect to is constantly changing.
2. **f** is not a vector-valued function, so as much as it seemed similar to a divergence operator for me, I doubt there's anything to do with it.
3. One of my professors (not specialised in the area of tensors) suggested that it looked very similar to the multivariable chain rule, but I'm not sure since the coordinates themselves aren't functions of another common variable (as far as I know).

Any help to put me on the right track here is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like an exterior derivative: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I see, it does look a lot like it, but unfortunately I haven't started differential geometry yet so most of these concepts are escaping me haha. I guess I'll come back to this problem once I'm comfortable with the topic, since I previously thought some multivariable calc was enough to start. Thanks!

Comment: Chain rule and exterior derivative are in this case [identical](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4761279/clarification-on-treating-a-variable-as-constant-in-partial-derivatives-vs-allo#comment10109091_4761279).